# Python - Is it better practice to check if a string is in a string, or list/tuple

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

I recently came across something that puzzled me: I was comparing to pieces of code and found that they both checked if a string was in a certain set differently. Here is what I mean:

**First one:**

```py
a = "+"
if a in "+-*/":
    print("yes")
```

**Second one:**

```py
a = "+"
if a in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
    print("yes")
```

Which one should I use? By that I mean which one is more pythonic?

Comment: Take a look at this [Page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for a comprehensive list of complexities. The answer provided below is in fact faster as `O(1)` rather than `O(n)`.

Comment: @TheLazyScripter well, building any of these data structures once to test membership once is still O(N)

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity is the same, so either work, and are the same/extremely similar speeds.

If you want something better

```
a = "+"
if a in {"+", "-", "*", "/"}:
    print("yes")
```

this will search for "+" in a set,
and since sets have constant look up time, it will be marginally faster than searching a list or string

Comment: generally, you dont want to use a set literal for this. Although the current CPython implementation optimizes this to a cached set. But you don't want to rely on that